# Prepopulate initial values for fields in the Django Admin without slugifying

Tags: python, django

In the Django admin, I can set a slug field to fill in automatically using prepopulated_fields.  How can I set a field to fill in using a different function, for example just basic concatenation instead of lowercase and spaces-to-hyphens ?

Answer (score 1):

There is no out of the box support for this (assuming you're talking replacing the exact, live editing that preopulated_fields provides).

The slug function is written in JavaScript, in `django/contrib/admin/media/js/urlify.js`

You could potentially insert a new script in the `ModelAdmin` extra JS property, but make sure your admin page doesn't actually need the "real" slugify script :)